# How to translate ESRI cursor example to pyQgis?

Tags: python, pyqgis

For example, how to translate this code into pyqgis?

```
    rows = gp.UpdateCursor("D:/St_Johns/data.mdb/roads")
    row = rows.Next()

    while row:
       row.buffer_distance = row.road_type * 100
       rows.UpdateRow(row)
       print row
       row = rows.Next()
```

errata:
buffer_distance is a calculate column
road_type is a calumn with calculate value

Follow your advice I type this code in to python windows:

```
>>> from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsFeature
>>> layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"D:\fold", "boundingBoxes.shp", "ogr")
>>> road_type_index = layer.fieldNameIndex("road_type")
>>> buffer_distance_index = layer.fieldNameIndex("buffer_dis")
>>> layer.select(layer.pendingAllAttributesList())
>>> layer.startEditing()
True
>>> for feature in layer:
...     newvalue = feature.attributeMap()[road_type_index].toInt()[0] * 100
...     feature.changeAttribute(buffer_distance_index, newvalue)
...     layer.updateFeature(feature)
...
```

next when I press "enter" the qgis (1.7.4) crash and exit

Comment: is buffer_distance a column?  I don't know arcpy

Comment: sorry I just add errata

Comment: so is buffer_distance created within this code block or created before.  Just so I can understand what is needed from a pyqgis point of view.

Comment: I have updated my code example to show what needs to go in QgsVectorLayer better. See `layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"D:\fold\boundingBoxes.shp", "boundingBoxes", "ogr")`

Comment: you can also check, `layer.isValid()` to make sure you have a valid layer before moving on

Comment: I check this advice, but qgis crash. (I also check this on the another computer)

Comment: See my last edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should get you started

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsFeature
layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"D:\fold\boundingBoxes.shp", "boundingBoxes", "ogr")

road_type_index = layer.fieldNameIndex("road_type")
buffer_distance_index = layer.fieldNameIndex("buffer_distance")

layer.select(layer.pendingAllAttributesList())

layer.startEditing()
for feature in layer:
   newvalue = feature.attributeMap()[road_type_index].toInt()[0] * 100
   feature.changeAttribute(buffer_distance_index, newvalue)
   layer.updateFeature(feature)

layer.commitChanges()
```

If in **1.7.4** try this

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsFeature
layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"D:\fold\boundingBoxes.shp", "boundingBoxes", "ogr")

road_type_index = layer.fieldNameIndex("road_type")
buffer_distance_index = layer.fieldNameIndex("buffer_distance")

layer.select(layer.pendingAllAttributesList())

layer.startEditing()
for feature in layer:
   newvalue = feature.attributeMap()[road_type_index].toInt()[0] * 100
   layer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(),buffer_distance_index,newvalue) 

layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: don't post code in the comments.  It's hard to read.  Edit your answer to include the code you have tried.

Comment: I tried version for 1.7.4, but still  crashes QGIS. Later I will test on the another computer.

Comment: Can you print the values of road_type_index and buffer_distance_index

Comment: yes, values are print correctly

Comment: I tried call script by  `execfile(r'C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\python\plugins\exec.py')`   but without success   

(*exec.py is code for 1.7.4)

Answer (score 0):

[Geopandas](https://geopandas.org/) provides a very intuitive way to update feature attributes. For example, the following is how you would use Geopandas and [`.itertuples()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples) to update rows as you would an Esri Update Cursor:

```
import geopandas as gpd

shp = '/path/to/your/shapefile.shp'

# Read shp
data = gpd.read_file(shp)

# Iterate over rows and update buffer_distance field
for row in data.itertuples():
    data.at[row.Index, 'buffer_distance'] = row.road_type *100

# Write to shapefile
data.to_file('/path/to/your/shapefile_updated.shp')
```