# QGIS equivalent to arcpy.SearchCursor?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

What is the equivalent in QGIS (or other FOSS) to this:

```py
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(table,
                          fields="ORIG_FID; field1; field2; field3; field4",
                          sort_fields="ORIG_FID A")

for row in rows:
```

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24849/how-to-translate-esri-cursor-example-to-pyqgis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [PyQGIS Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook)'s section on *[Using Vector Layers](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#iterating-over-vector-layer)*.

Hacking together the examples there:

```
# The expression will filter the features where the field "location_name" contains
# the word "Lake" (case insensitive)
exp = QgsExpression('location_name ILIKE \'%Lake%\'')
request = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)
request.setSubsetOfAttributes(['name','id'],layer.pendingFields())
for feature in layer.getFeatures(request):
    # do whatever you need with the feature
```

Also, see this question for some other hints: [What are QGIS Arcpy Equivalent Functions for Update/Delete Row/Field?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67255/what-are-qgis-arcpy-equivalent-functions-for-update-delete-row-field)

Comment: Thank you Richard, I'll check this approach! Although at first sight I don't see the "sort fields" option.

Comment: @Albert As a newbie, I am also not seeing where in the Cookbook they show examples of the sort.  However, I did find this answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/138769/43

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.getFeatures()`](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a412ac9a3563e542485927bde03397962), this returns all layer field values:

> Query the provider for features specified in request.

```
for feature in table.getFeatures():
    if feature['myField'] == someVariable:
        # do something
```